# Which Azure SQL products allow me to deploy SSIS packages?

Tags: azure, ssis

We are looking at migrating our SQL Server, SSIS packages from an on-premise environment to Azure.  Which Azure SQL Server products provide SSIS functionality?  I understand the data lake environment does, but can I, for example, simply deploy an Azure general purpose single instance database and get SSIS? Just to be clear, I want to deploy 3 SQL databases and use SSIS to ETL data between them without having a VM or running SSIS on-premise.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but you should use Azure Data Factory which supports SSIS packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SQL Managed Instances. Here are useful links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/how-to-migrate-ssis-packages-managed-instance

PS: study the alternative I've left as comment too (for cost saving reasons)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer Thiago, from the first URL it seems to indictate that SSIS is not part of managed instances (table at the bottom)

Comment: Also, I see this:  Managed instance supports SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) and can host SSIS catalog (SSISDB) that stores SSIS packages, but they are executed on a managed Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime (IR) in Azure Data Factory (ADF), see Create Azure-SSIS IR in ADF. To compare the SSIS features in SQL Database, see Compare an Azure SQL Database single database, elastic pool, and managed instance.  **Seems contradictory**

Comment: hmm interesting. I had the idea it was fully supported (without ADF). I'm afraid that your only option is to install them on a VM then

Comment: I marked this as correct since it is technically both a SQL Managed Instance and SSIS Integration Runtime (Azure Data Factory) required.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have found a more comprehensive answer here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Azure Data Factory hosts the runtime engine for SSIS packages on Azure. The runtime engine is called the Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime (Azure-SSIS IR). For more info, see Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime.

[image]

Effectively you were right, Thiago - it's both Azure data factory for SSIS Integration Runtime and a SQL Server managed instance!